# Can we create a lookup relation between 2 lists even if the 2 lists exceeds the threshold limitation

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, list-view-threshold

We have 3 sharePoint online lists A,B & C .. where lists B & C has a lookup field to list A. now all of the 3 lists will contain around 1 million record.. so when we create or edit items from lists B & C will we be able to select the related list A item? or the lookup field inside lists B & C create/edit forms will not show the 1 million options? we will be using the modern ui.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, creating a lookup column to list A which has over 5000 items is not available.

Similar question:

[New item with lookup on list with more than 5k items](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/224776/new-item-with-lookup-on-list-with-more-than-5k-items)

Comment: that looks weird ...

Comment: It caused by the list view threshold is 5000.